# In a boost multi_index container, is a "default index" defined?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Here is a container of ints with a sequence index and a hashed index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
    boost::multi_index_container<
        int,
        bmi::indexed_by<
            bmi::sequenced<>,
            bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::identity<int>>
        >
    > c;
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) c.push_back(i);
    for (int j : c) std::cout << " " << j;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note I did not use `get` in the second loop.  Is the behavior defined in this case?  (E.g., "This is the same as using `.get<0>()`".)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I do see different output on boost 1.70, please add which version of boost you are using

Comment: Here is wanbox live example for boost 1.72 https://wandbox.org/permlink/96OSdRxraauwNiKw

Comment: I believe I'm using 1.68.0.

Comment: I used link above from wandbox and changed  to use gcc 7.3.0 and boost 1.68, still cannot reproduce your result. Looks like something is wrong on your side.

Comment: Your demonstration shows the result I was hoping for, so I consider this answered.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @slava resolved the confusion I revealed in my original question, and there were no answers posted.  So I have repurposed this to my real question, about "default indices".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, index #0 is the default in the sense explained [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort):

*The functionality of index #0 can be accessed directly from a multi_index_container object without using `get<0>()`: for instance, `es.begin()` is equivalent to `es.get<0>().begin()`.*

Comment: Thank you!  Multi-index has lots of details :-)